# How do I draw a line and a gradient in my table header section viewForHeaderInSection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've added some titles in my UITableView header section and I'd like to draw a white line at the bottom and a a gray gradient going from top to bottom.

At the moment in `viewForHeaderInSection` I have create a view with labels for my headings. I'm now trying to draw a white line, which I've managed using a 1 pixel high label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you show create an UIVIew subclass, say HeaderView in which you will draw your line:

```
@implementation HeaderView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    //add a gradient:
    CAGradientLayer *layer = [[[CAGradientLayer alloc] init] autorelease]
    [gradientLayer setBounds:[self bounds]]
    [gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil]];
    [[self layer] insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

    //draw line
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0, 0, 1); 
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, rect.size.height-1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint( ctx, rect.size.width, rect.size.height-1);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);


}
@end
```

and then in your table delegate:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
    HeaderView* customView = [[[HeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 360.0, 20.0)] autorelease];

    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 100.0, 20.0); 
    headerLabel.text = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    [customView addSubview:headerLabel];
    [headerLabel release];

    return customView;
```

}

Comment: Romain, please see edits above, I've made some small color changes to your code. However, the gradient is out of the header section area?  and I'm unable to get the line to be white. I added a label with height 1 which is the last image, so I know the gray line isn't height 1.

Comment: CoreGraphics will always draw across pixel boundaries meaning that if you have a one pixel line, it will be drawn between two pixels, making it appear as a chunky, gross 2 pixel line that has washed out color.

For your horizontal line, you need to offset the Y coordinate by 0.5 and vice versa for vertical lines.

Comment: I needed to make a correction `[gradientLayer setFrame:rect];` and after fixing my bottom line with CrystalSkulls fix my line was hidden behind the gradient. So I stuck with my one pixel label. All looks quite good :)

Comment: I had to change the first *layer by *gradientLayer, and the change that Jules did.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered but I had problems getting the line to draw over the gradient. I figured there may be others that are having the same issue so here is how I solved it. This works for iOS 4x

CustomTableViewSectionHeaderWithLine.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomTableViewSectionHeaderWithLine : UIView {
    UIColor *topColor;
    UIColor *bottomColor;
    UIColor *lineColor;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *topColor, *bottomColor, *lineColor;
@end
```

CustomTableViewSectionHeaderWithLine.m

```
#import "CustomTableViewSectionHeaderWithLine.h"


@implementation CustomTableViewSectionHeaderWithLine
@synthesize topColor;
@synthesize bottomColor;
@synthesize lineColor;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Set the colors to something heinous so if you forget you can know immediately
        if ([self topColor] == nil) topColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        if ([self bottomColor] == nil) bottomColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        if ([self lineColor] == nil) lineColor = [UIColor redColor];        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    //[super drawRect:rect];

    //add a gradient:
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [[[CAGradientLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [gradientLayer setBounds:[self bounds]];
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height -1);
    [gradientLayer setFrame:newRect];
    [gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[topColor CGColor], (id)[bottomColor CGColor], nil]];
    [[self layer] insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

    //draw line
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    // This gets the RGB Float values from the color initialized for lineColor
    const float* colors = CGColorGetComponents( lineColor.CGColor );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, colors[0], colors[1], colors[2], 1);    
    //CGContextSetGrayStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 1);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint( ctx, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Usage (Implement these two methods in your TableViewDelegate

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CustomTableViewSectionHeaderWithLine *customView = [[[CustomTableViewSectionHeaderWithLine alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 360.0, 25.0)] autorelease];
    [customView setTopColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [customView setBottomColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [customView setLineColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 10, 18)] autorelease];
    label.text = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [customView addSubview:label];

    return customView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

People, who do not want to subclass the view (UILabel/UIButton) etc...

```
-(void) drawUnderlinedLabel {
    NSString *string = [forgetButton titleForState: UIControlStateNormal];
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont: forgetButton.titleLabel.font];
    CGRect buttonFrame = forgetButton.frame;
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(buttonFrame.origin.x + buttonFrame.size.width - stringSize.width, buttonFrame.origin.y + stringSize.height + 1 , stringSize.width, 2);
    UILabel *lineLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
    lineLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //[forgetButton addSubview:lineLabel];
    [self.view addSubview: lineLabel];
}
```